# Angular.js ng-click not registering ng-model on form

Tags: angularjs

So for some reason I am only getting the password on click. I've tried moving the div around. I used a div instead of a form. Been trying to figure this out. Please Help.

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-3">
        <form class="form-login">
            <h4>Welcome</h4>
            <input type="text" ng.model="vm.user.name" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="username" />
            </br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.user.password" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="password" />
            </br>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <span class="group-btn">     
                    <button type="submit" ng-click="vm.authenticate(vm.user)" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">login <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why is there an ng.model instead of ng-model

Comment: ha that would be the answer...it's been a long day @BobThomas if you want to put it as answer I'll checkmark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hya you used ng.model instead of ng-model :3

And a long day it has been indeed